# Unable to delete artifact in apache archiva

Tags: maven, archiva

[image: ScreenShot]I am getting the following error when I try to delete an uploaded artifact from Archiva.

```
ERROR:Repository exception: Unable to write metadata file:/usrdata/tomcatapi/tomcat/api/jars/Apache-Commons/1/maven-metadata.xml - /usrdata/tomcatapi/tomcat/api/jars/Apache-Commons/1/maven-metadata.xml (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error signifies that the repository chosen was wrong! The file was in some other repository!